# Invalid config field backend model

Tags: admin, model, backend, csv, exception

I'm having some trouble understanding why magento is throwing this exception when I attempt to access my backend.  This appears, at least to my eyes, to be configured correctly.  Any ideas?

Below is my modules config.xml (located at ProjectName/etc/config.xml):

```
<global>
    ....       
    <models>
        <projectname>
            <class>NameSpace_ProjectName_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>projectname_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </projectname>
        <projectname_mysql4>
            <class>NameSpace_ProjectName_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <projectname>
                    <table>project_name_table</table>
                </projectname>
            </entities>
        </projectname_mysql4>
    </models>
    ....
</global>
```

Below is my system.xml (located at ProjectName/etc/system.xml):

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <cataloginventory>
            <groups>
                <options>
                    <fields>
                        <namespace_projectname_import translate="label">
                            <label>Import project</label>
                            <frontend_type>import</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>projectname/csv</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </namespace_projectname_import>
                    </fields>
                </options>
            </groups>
        </cataloginventory>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Below is my model (located at ProjectName/Model/CSV.php):

```
class NameSpace_ProjectName_Model_CSV extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    public function save()
    {
        Mage::log("this is configured correctly");
        Mage::getResourceModel('projectname/projectname')->uploadData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to rename your file **Csv.php** and your class **NameSpace_ProjectName_Model_Csv**.

It should work :)

**EDIT**

Magento use the **uc_words()** methods (can be found in *app/code/core/Mage/Core/Functions.php*).

```
function uc_words($str, $destSep='_', $srcSep='_')
{
    return str_replace(' ', $destSep, ucwords(str_replace($srcSep, ' ', $str)));
}
```

Comment: where is uc_words applicable?  Is this why casing so sensitive in filename definition?

Comment: when you use Mage::getModel(), Mage::getBlock() or Mage::helper() Magento call the Mage_Core_Model_Config class.
You can check the getGroupedClassName() method. At the end it calls the uc_words() function